# Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1, file "Code") - Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been coding less than a week, but I would think I would not have this much trouble trying to solve this error. Looked through other examples, but I am not likely knowledgeable enough to figure out how they apply to mine, 'cause none of them solved my problem. Here is the code:

```js
function clearButtonClick() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  Logger.log('sheet.getName(): ' + sheet.getName());
  
  if (sheet.getName() !== "TimeCardEntry") {return;};
  
  sheet.getRange(8,2,12,12).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(4,4).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(4,11).clearContent();
}


function submitButtonClick(){
  //Begining of entry8 transfer
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //Makes the active spreadsheet available for the program to act on
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Makes the active sheet available
  Logger.log('The active sheet is: ' + sheet.getName()); //Writes the sheet name to the log so it can be checked
  
  while(sheet.getName() =="TimeCardEntry"){  //If you are on the correct sheet when you try to run...
//change 8
    var cellB8 = sheet.getRange(8,2).getValue(); //Pulls in the value of "B8"
//change 8    
    if(cellB8 === "") {return}; //If B8 is not blank, or in other words, B8 has something in it, then...
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TimesheetRecord"); //Pulls in the target sheet name
      var arrayOfData = []; //Creates the array to temporarily hold the data until it writes to target sheet
    
      
      var weekBegining = sheet.getRange(4,11).getValue(); //Stores the value of the "Sunday at the Begining of the Week Date"
      var employName = sheet.getRange(4,4).getValue();  //Stores the name of the employee from D4
//change 8      
      var entry8 = sheet.getRange(8,2,1,9);  //pulls in row 8 data to be worked on
//change 8      
      var entry8Data = entry8.getValues()[0]; //pulls row 8 into an inner array
//change 8      
      Logger.log('Line 8 data is:' = entry8Data);  //logs what the data is so you can make sure it got the right stuff    
      entry*Data.splice (0,0,weekBegining,employName);  //Add weekBegining and employName values to the entry data array
//change 8
      arrayOfData.push(entry8Data);  //Push row data for entry 8 into an outer array because setValues() can't use nested arrays
      Logger.log('Array of data is: ' + arrayOfData); //writes the combined data array to the log
      
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow(); //stores the number of the last row with entries in the target sheet
      Logger.log('Last Row is: ' + lastRow);  //logs what the last row is for reference
//change 8      
      targetSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,entry8Data.length).seValues(arrayOfData); //Adds 1 row to the lastfilled row then selects that row (1st empty one) and 1 row deep by the number of columns in the arrayOfData then copies the arrayOfData values to it.
//change 8      
      sheet.getRange(8,2,1,9).clearContent();  //goes back to the original sheet and deletes the row 8 data.
      
    }
  }


function emailLog(){  
//Send an email to yourself with the log from running this script so you can see if any values were wrong
//Comment all this out once the script work right  
  var emailRecipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var emailSubject = 'Log of the last run of Paradigm Weekly Time Card' ;
  var emailBody = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipient, emailSubject, emailBody);
}
```

[image: Google App Script Error Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1, file "Code")]

Be gentle, it' my first time. ;)

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If so please accept that answer.

Comment: Sorry, still new at this. Forgot that you needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on the line:

```
Logger.log('Line 8 data is:' = entry8Data);
```

I think you mean:

```
Logger.log('Line 8 data is:' + entry8Data);
```

Also, best practice is to always use `===` to compare things, never `==` :)